# Could + Past Perfect ? "I could had been"

Tags: modal-verbs, past-perfect

Is "**could**" ever followed by the **past perfect**? For example, we can say:

> I could *have* been here before he arrived.

but (I think) the following is wrong:

> I could *had* been here before he arrived.

Is there any situation where we can use the past perfect?

---

**Edit**: Are [these](https://www.google.it/search?tbm=bks&hl=it&q=%22could%20had%22) examples incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen any verb form following [*modal* verbs](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/modal-verb?q=modal+verbs) other than a **bare infinitive**.

The bare infinitive of to *have* is **have**. You should always use *have* after could. There are many typos on the internet, i.e., *could + **had**+ past participle* and you should compare it with *could + **have** + past participle*.

If you Google "could had" now, you get 395,000 hits, but many of them in the first page are questions about whether *could + had* is correct or not.

If you Google "could have" now, you get 323 million results.

Sometimes, people write *could + **of** + past participle*, but it is also a [mistake](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/could-of-or-could-have).

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: I agree that there are many typos, my main "concern" is that the link I've provived is actually from _books_. If no one else says anything in the next few hours I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @drM. There was an interesting question on English Language and Usage, ["To be pound of something": Correct meaning and usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305098/to-be-pound-of-something-correct-meaning-and-usage) which is similar to your question. It is about I am *proud* of and I am **pound** of. There are more examples of typos on the internet. Just because Google Books search shows some examples of typos doesn't mean that the typos are correct.

Comment: @drM. - Those still look like typos.  Books are not immune from typos.